# Mapa do Brasil - qual a melhor forma de fazer?

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho o seguinte mapa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o cliente passar o mouse em cima de um estado, tem que mudar de cor. Eu pensei em fazer várias divs, para montar o mapa. Só que isso irá gerar um problema, como as divs são quadradas, terá que passar o mouse bem no centro do estado.

Existe alguma outra alternativa?

Comment: Dependendo da sua utilização, vc pode usar o fusioncharts->  http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/fusionmaps/?map=brazil

Comment: Talvez fazer em SVG, ou então do modo mais trabalhoso e antigo.. que é mapear todos os estados e depois criar um efeito hover/troca de imagem.

Comment: Eu criei uma diretiva do plugin JQVMap em Jquery para AngularJS
[link github](https://github.com/rangellucas/angular-jqvmap-vector)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Isso pode te ajudar:

https://github.com/felipeduardo/mapa-brasil-svg/blob/master/index.html

O mapa é quase o mesmo, é só mudar o style.

**https://jsfiddle.net/9yp2L7ab/**

Comment: Reparei que o projeto citado não informa qual a licença de uso, só diz "Creditos to olx.com.br" - e não vi nenhuma indicação que a OLX tenha disponibilizado o mapa para uso gratuito. Se eu estiver enganado, por favor me corrijam, pois também estou em busca de uma solução desse tipo.

Comment: P.S. Encontrei na Wikipedia [um arquivo SVG semelhante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brasil#/media/File:Brazil_Labelled_Map.svg), este licenciado sob Creative Commons (CC-BY-SA). O processo pra implementar o *hover* é a mesma.